# How to set a panel/ window transparent in extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How to set a panel or a window transparent (half)?
Via CSS or set the html code?
The extjs version is 4.0.7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this with CSS.

Add this config to your panel:

```
bodyStyle: 'background:transparent;'
```

or

```
bodyStyle: 'opacity:0.5;'
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I apply frame:true, it will be different. The background opacity will be 1. I don't know if it is the bug of Extjs. Thanks man.