# Ext js grid seethrough

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I want to have an Ext Js grid which is completely transparent. Is this possible? I have tried multiple things to achieve this. Changing style of individual cells, changing styles of rows, overriding ext js CSS. But nothing seems to work.

Sorry for not posting any code but I am interested more in the correct approach

Example using renderer:

```
metaData.style = "background-color:transparent !important";
```

Example using bodyStyle:

```
bodyStyle: 'background:transparent;'
```

Thaks in advance

Comment: post sample html in your grid

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049013/how-to-set-a-panel-window-transparent-in-extjs-4/14052674

Answer (score 0):

Just add to you grid:

Code 3.4

```
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({     
          ...

       style: {
            opacity: 0.5
           }
          ...})
```

Code 4.2:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
          ...

       style: {
            opacity: 0.5
           }
          ...})
```

It`s a standart attribute of grid in [3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-cfg-style) and [4.x](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-style) Ext JS

Comment: This makes also the font transparent

Comment: and what result do you want? Font 100% opacity and cells, titles, background absolutely transparent?